# Laravel Form Request Validation Error Issue

Tags: forms, validation, laravel, request

I'm using the Form Request Validation (Laravel 5) to validate my input.
It validates my form, but when it doesn't get through the validation Laravel should return automatically an in-built error.
But it stays on the same page (without refreshing) and without showing an error, neither putting the input into the database

```
//Controller
public function store(StoreProjectPostRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    Project::create($input);

    return Redirect::route('projects.index')->with('message', 'Project created');
}



//Request
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:15|alpha_num',
        'slug' => 'alpha_dash|required|max:10',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full controller and request files? When it passes validation, do you get the redirect?

Comment: I got it, was stupidity by forgetting to add the error into my view/html

Comment: It happens, glad you got it figured out.